# C# client connection to SockJS over STOMP websocket erver?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, client

Making Unity client with c#, server is SockJS over STOMP Websocket Server.
WebsocketSharp doesn't work.

I think just Websocket server can connect by WebsocketSharp,
but SockJS over STOMP Websocket Server can't connect by WebsocketSharp and other libs.

What do I use to connect with the server??

Comment: There are javascript  clients for stomp. Just google that.

Comment: I know that. But I need to use C#

Comment: Just look it up in Github e.g. https://github.com/huhuhong/websocket-csharp-net-stomp-client